# New line at end of file skipped while appending by to_csv() function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, append, export-to-csv, newline

I am trying to write some data from a pandas dataframe into a file, with a blank line between two chunks of data as

```
File Start
0 1
0 2
0 3

0 1
0 2
0 3
```

For this purpose I wrote the following code in jupyter notebook.

```
fname = "test.dat"

df0 = pd.DataFrame({0:[0, 0, 0],
       1:[1, 2, 3]})

f = open(fname, 'w')
f.write("File Start\n")
f.close()

f = open(fname, 'a')

df0.to_csv(fname, mode='a', sep = " ", index = False, header = False)

f.write("\n")

df0.to_csv(fname, mode='a', sep = " ", index = False, header = False)

f.close()

print(df0)
```

which gives me the following output where there is no newline between the blocks of data.

```
File Start
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 1
0 2
0 3
```

But instead if I have the `f.close()` statement before the second `df0.to_csv()` call I get the expected output. Does this mean the newline by `f.write("\n")` is not written to the file until `f.close()` is called ?

This is especially an issue when I have several blocks to write and I need to use a 'for' loop, where I would rather not open and close the file everytime. (The code below does not add a newline between subsequent `df0.to_csv()` calls)

```
fname = "test.dat"

df0 = pd.DataFrame({0:[0, 0, 0],
       1:[1, 2, 3]})

f = open(fname, 'w')
f.write("File Start\n")
f.close()

f = open(fname, 'a')

for i in range(2):
    df0.to_csv(fname, mode='a', sep = " ", index = False, header = False)
    f.write("\n")


f.close()

print(df0)
```

Is there any way I can add newline characters without opening and closing the file everytime ?

Comment: so, right off the bat, `f` is never used until you do `f.write("\n")`, so the `f` file cursor is still at position 0 (try `print(f.tell())` before the `.write`). A simple solution would be to open the file in append mode *after* you've written the first part. Note, where `.close` is called affects this because writing to the file is *buffered* automatically. Fundamentally, you shouldn't be relying on this, and you don't need to here.

Comment: The **other option** is to pass `f` to `to_csv` instead of `filename` (and omit the `mode` argument). You should also be using a context manager to do this.

Comment: Fundamentally, trying to keep a file handle open while *other things are writing to that file* is going to lead to lots of quirky, platform-dependent behavior. Just don't do it. Wrap the newline-writing in a function if it feels like too much code to repeat. Don't be lazy

Comment: sorry, the cursor will be at position 11 in this example. In any case, the buffering is the issue. The actual file isn't written to until you use `f.close()`. You can't turn buffering of in text mode either. And opening it in binary mode while another thing is writing to it in text mode is just fraught with landmines.

Comment: So, as a bottom line, do I have to open and close the file in the for loop @juanpa.arrivillaga? My primary concern was to prevent opening and closed a file too many times, because I have this (unsure) notion that opening and closing of a file is an expensive operation (or at least leads to complication in the memory when its done too many times, like 1e4 say).

Comment: by the way, passing `f` to `to_csv` worked @juanpa.arrivillaga. Not I don't have to repeat the opening and closing of the file in the for a loop.

Comment: there's some overhead to it, but I think this is a perfect example of "premature optimization is the root of all evil", but note, `to_csv` will simply open the file again if it is passed a string anyway